# How to Fix Error "ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install" while executing the program in physical device Mobile in Flutter Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

While executing the program in physical device Mobile in Flutter Dart, the following error appears:

```
ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install, Error launching application on Mobile Device Name Here
```

Actually this problem occurs in the Android Studio's Console when we try to run out Flutter Dart program in physical device like Mobile. This problem is occurs many times while executing the flutter program in Mobile.

When the Error

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1, Performing Streamed Install, Error launching application on physical Device name.
```

is thrown in the Android Studio Console, I unplug the physical device mobile from cable and re-launch the flutter dart program on physical device mobile. By doing this, I almost solve this error problem every time. The solution of this problem is that unplugging the cable and then re-running the Application in Mobile device OR restarts the Application.

After doing this, this error problem will solved. There will always need to restart and re run the flutter dart program on the physical device after unplug the cable from mobile and Laptop and then again the plug in the cable with mobile and laptop and then restart and re run the flutter dart program on your physical device.

Answer (score 1):

unplug the physical device mobile from cable and re-launch the flutter dart program on physical device mobile. By doing this, I almost solve this error problem every time. The solution of this problem is that unplugging the cable and then re-running the Application in Mobile device OR restarts the Application.

After doing this, this error problem will solved. There will always need to restart and re run the flutter dart program on the physical device after unplug the cable from mobile and Laptop and then again the plug in the cable with mobile and laptop and then restart and re run the flutter dart program on your physical device.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the ADB server by running this commands in your terminal

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```